# How can I define one specific fragment instance's style/theme in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-theme, android-styles

I've created a UI component in my app that is used in multiple places (some light, some dark) and needs to be [lifecycle-aware](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), so I've converted it into a [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).  I instantiate this fragment exclusively using `<fragment>` tags in my activities' XML layout files.

I'm struggling to find a way to enable the fragment to render its own controls and text in a colour that's appropriate for its background as set by its parent element.  Currently, no matter what theme or style I set on the parent view or the `<fragment>` tag itself, the fragment controls are shown as if on a light background:

[image: the fragment as rendered on a light background]
[image: the fragment as rendered on a dark background]

I've tried setting `android:theme` on the `<fragment>` to both `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark` and `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` in an attempt to get the text light-coloured on the dark background, but with no luck.

I would prefer not to program this colour switching into the fragment itself, because I feel like the theming/styling framework must surely be able to handle this.

Ideally, I would also be able to incorporate an icon into this fragment at a later stage with its colour matching the text.  My priority right now though is getting the correct text colour.

What is the correct way to tell one specific instance of a fragment, “you are on a dark background instead of a light one,” or “you need to render your text and controls in a light colour instead of a dark one,” and have it render accordingly?

#### Update

I've [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47303054/4877269) that does it by implementing a custom attribute on the `<fragment>` tag and initialising from it in my fragment's code.

#### Previous update

[Chris Banes' article on Theme vs. Style](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/) states:

> One thing to note is that `android:theme` in Lollipop propogates to all children declared in the layout:
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark">
>
>     <!-- Anything here will also have a dark theme -->
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```
>
> Your children can set their own theme if needed.

This is distinctly **not** happening in my case with the use of fragments—it seems that the `android:theme` attribute of the `<fragment>` tag in the XML is not being considered at all during the inflation, but should be.

My fragment's `onCreateView` method is quite standard:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState
) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_search, container, false);
}
```

I suppose either the `container` is not getting the theme to begin with, or the inflater is not “attaching” that information to the inflated child view.  I'm not proficient enough in Android development to determine which (if either) is the case.

Comment: When you apply `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"` to `<fragment>`, what is the output?

Comment: On my `<fragment>`, the attribute is completely ignored, and the text remains dark.  On some random nearby `<EditText>`, the text turns white as expected.

Comment: In the screenshot the first line is a fragment, and the second line is a standard `EditText` and both of them are applied `android:theme`?

Comment: Both of the `EditText`s shown above (technically `AutoCompleteTextView`s) are instances of the fragment in question.  The one on the light background had no theme explicitly applied, because it was already rendering as expected.  The one on the dark background had the theme explicitly applied, but it was ignored.

Comment: What do you mean the `<fragment>` tag? How do you manage your fragments?

Comment: I use `<fragment>` tags in my activities' XML layout files to create instances of this fragment where needed, and I let the Android framework do whatever remaining management is required.  The fragment instances create, start, stop and destroy as expected with their parent activities.  The only problem I'm facing is the lack of theme propagation from their containing views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the desired effect by explicitly specifying the parent container's theme in a custom attribute on the `<fragment>` tag, and manually reading it during the fragment's initialisation.

#### XML layout file using the `<fragment>`

1. Ensure the root element of the XML has the following `xmlns:app` attribute:

   ```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   ```
2. Add a custom attribute of `app:customTheme` to the `<fragment>` tag:

   ```
   <fragment
       android:name="net.alexpeters.myapp.TaskSearchFragment"
       app:customTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
   ```

#### Attributes XML file `values/attrs.xml`

Add the `declare-styleable` element shown below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <!-- ↓↓↓ -->
        <declare-styleable name="TaskSearchFragment">
            <attr name="customTheme" format="reference" />
        </declare-styleable>
        <!-- ↑↑↑ -->
    </resources>
```

#### `Fragment` subclass

1. Add an instance variable to hold a custom theme ID:

   ```
   private @StyleRes int themeResId;
   ```
2. Add a constant to handle the case where no custom theme is passed in:

   ```
   private static final int NO_CUSTOM_THEME = 0;
   ```
3. Override the `onInflate` method as follows:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onInflate(
           @NonNull Context context,
           AttributeSet attrs,
           Bundle savedInstanceState
   ) {
       super.onInflate(context, attrs, savedInstanceState);
       TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
               attrs,
               R.styleable.TaskSearchFragment
       );
       themeResId = a.getResourceId(
               R.styleable.TaskSearchFragment_customTheme,
               NO_CUSTOM_THEME
       );
       a.recycle();
   }
   ```
4. Add some logic to the `onCreateView` method to inject the custom theme reference into the inflater:

   ```
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(
           @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
           @Nullable ViewGroup container,
           @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState
   ) {
       // ↓↓↓
       if (themeResId != NO_CUSTOM_THEME) {
           inflater = inflater.cloneInContext(
               new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), themeResId)
           );
       }
       // ↑↑↑
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_search, container, false);
   }
   ```

I'd prefer to just infer the parent container's theme somehow, but I don't know whether this is possible.

Failing that, I'd prefer to use a standard attribute (i.e. `android:theme`) instead of a custom one, but I don't know whether this is possible either.